# Postgre SQL odbc driver - Server closed the connection Unexpectedly

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, odbc, driver

I am trying to create a ODBC driver for my mongo db so that i can connect to my BI tool. Unfortunately, any of the drivers i downloaded doesnt work.
I tried postgre and i get the following error. Any help?  i googled for the same error and most of the solution is for checking the config file - but those are for other operating systems. I dont see any .conf file in Windows under Program files / Postgre filder

Error "Server close the connection unexpectedly" 
[image: Postgre SQL error]

Comment: Are you open to using a paid solution? If so, I'd recommend our MongoDB ODBC Driver: [http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/odbc/](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/mongodb/odbc/)

Comment: @JerodJohnson At this moment, only free version. Update - I tried the evaluation version of SiSense ODBC connector and it works. Just not sure why this guy wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/

I've used it on a windows service and it works great.

Comment: Installation has not been the problem. it is the configuration that i worries me

Comment: have you checked that the postgres is actually running on port 27017? the default port is 5432.

Comment: try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. My issue was resolved using this.

Comment: out of curiosity, have you tried the 32 bit version of the odbc administrator?  http://superuser.com/questions/419832/how-can-i-open-the-32-bit-odbc-data-source-administrator-in-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: @Karty are you sure about the port? Default port of postgresql is 5432

Comment: @VarshneyP. I am not using Postgre database. i am just using their ODBC driver to connect to Mongodb.. So i dont have any installation of their db where i have to change the port config..